# Concatenating two variables with an underscore

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to concatenate two variables to create a filename that has an underscore.
Lets call my variables `$FILENAME` and `$EXTENSION` where filename is read from a file.

```
FILENAME=Hello
EXTENSION=WORLD.txt
```

Now...

I have tried the following without success:

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_$EXTENSION
NAME=${FILENAME}'_'$EXTENSION
NAME=$FILENAME\\_$EXTENSION
```

I always get some kind of weird output. Usually the underscore first.

I need it to be

```
echo $NAME
Hello_WORLD.txt
```

Comment: Probably your script contains carriage return characters.

Comment: Yep that was it. :D

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
NAME=$(echo ${FILENAME}_${EXTENSION})
```

This works as well:

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_${EXTENSION}
```

Comment: The problem was the file where I was reading NAMEs from. Windows formatting... Your solution worked great after that. Thanks

Comment: The first command mangles the value of the variable and the use of a command substitution and `echo` cannot possibly help. The second command was already given in the question.

Comment: Yes! I love it. This was fücking annoying me for the longest while. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This works for me. When I use '$FILENAME_$EXTENSION', only values of '$EXTENSION' appears. Could you please help explain why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Your:

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_$EXTENSION
NAME=${FILENAME}'_'$EXTENSION
```

are all fine, so would be:

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_${EXTENSION}
NAME=$FILENAME'_'$EXTENSION
NAME=$FILENAME\_$EXTENSION
NAME=$FILENAME"_$EXTENSION"
```

(but certainly **not** <strike>`NAME=$(echo ${FILENAME}_${EXTENSION})`</strike> as [it uses `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [the `split+glob` operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)).

```
NAME=$FILENAME_$EXTENSION
```

would have been the same as:

```
NAME=${FILENAME_}${EXTENSION}
```

as `_` (contrary to `\` or `'`) is a valid character in a variable name.

Your problem is that you had lines delimited with CRLF instead of just LF, which meant that those variable content ended in CR character.

The CR character, when written to a terminal tells the terminal to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. So `Hello<CR>_WORLD.TXT<CR>` when sent to a terminal would show as `_WORLD.TXT` (overriding the `Hello`).

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to using the `${FILENAME}_${EXTENSION}` syntax mentioned above.

I used to use `$()` when I needed to concatenate two variables with an underscore. For example, `$YYYYMMDD$()_$HHMMSS` to generate a filename containing a timestamp in the format of YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS. The middle `$()` returns nothing and breaks the two variables apart.

I've used `time` to measure the assignments using the `$YYYYMMDD$()_$HHMMSS` method and some of those above, and they've all reported 0ms on the old server I'm using this on. Performance doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You should raise a new question for that. `$()` does fork a subshell in a few shells (some optimise it  away) . It's also hijacking an operator for something it's not been designed for. `${x}_y` is what you want.

Comment: What do you mean, “That doesn’t answer the question.”?   It’s not a great answer, but it is an answer.

Comment: Edited to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use variables in lowercase (it is the best practice).
So, I'll use filename and extension instead of FILENAME and EXTENSION

As you say that “filename is read from a file”, I'll assume that the script is:

```
read -r filename  <file.txt
extension=World.txt
```

And that you want to concatenate both variables $filename and $extension with an underscore `_`.
The examples you provide (except: no double \) do work correctly here:

```
name=${filename}_$extension
name=${filename}'_'$extension
name=$filename\_$extension
```

As some other:

```
name="${filename}"'_'"${extension}"
name="$filename"'_'"$extension"
name="${filename}_${extension}"
```

So, your problem is not with how the variables are stick together, but with the contents of the vars. It seems reasonable to think that this:

```
read -r filename  <file.txt
```

will read a trailing carriage return `\r` if reading from a windows file.

One simple solution (for ksh,bash,zsh) is to remove all control characters from the read variable:

```
filename=${filename//[[:cntrl:]]/}
```

This could be simulated with a value that has a carriage return:

```
$ filename=$'Hello\r'
$ echo "starting<$filename>end"
>endting<Hello                       ### note the return to the start of line.
$ echo "starting<${filename//[[:cntrl:]]/}>end"
starting<Hello>end
```

Or, replacing the value of `filename`:

```
$ filename="${filename//[[:cntrl:]]/}"
$ echo "start<$filename>end"
start<Hello>end
```

#### Conclusion.

So this:

```
name="${filename//[[:cntrl:]]/}_${extension//[[:cntrl:]]/}"
```

Will get the correct value for `name` even if the other vars contain control characters.

Answer (score 0):

[Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88452/80216#254067),

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_$EXTENSION
```

is, of course, the best answer, and should be the accepted answer. 
But, in the spirit of [user208145’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88452/80216#325892), here’s an alternative:

```
UNDERSCORE='_'
NAME=$FILENAME$UNDERSCORE$EXTENSION
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use this: separate the separate vars with spaces and concatenate them using tr to remove the space.

```
TableNameToCreate="MyTable"
# concatenation work is done here 
$(echo "$TableNameToCreate _my_other_Info " | tr -d " ")

#Proof
echo "Var to create with var pasted as prefix to suffix
    $(echo "$TableNameToCreate _my_other_Info " | tr -d " ") 
. "

# create a new var
NewVar=$(echo "$TableNameToCreate _my_other_Info " | tr -d " ")

#proof
echo "$NewVar"
```

Comment: (1) This question has already been answered more than adequately.  (2) What does your answer do if the existing variable has special characters in it?

Comment: This does not address the issue with the variable containing a carriage return. It also removes spaces, something that may not be wanted.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Actually, unless I’m overlooking something, this handles carriage return just fine; spaces are the only problem.